# Changing raw IP to FQDN in connection strings - any potential issues?

Tags: sql-server, connection-string

**Our setup**

I have a small hosting setup consisting of an SQL Server (2008), a couple of webservers and an application server. They are not part of any domain - just a bunch of totally separate machines (but on the same switch).

**The problem**

We are currently using the server IP in the connection strings on the web and application servers. This is not optimal in case the server crashes and needs to be rebuild with a different IP (or for some other reason needs to change IP).

**Possible solution?**

What I thought I'd do is use a FQDN instead (e.g. sqlserver.mydomain.com). This has some potential issues:
- One more thing that can break (the DNS resolution)
- There might be a slight performance hit due to the DNS resolution (though probably theoretical)
- There would be a delay when changing the DNS-record due to TTL.

To mitigate this I thought I'd add the FQDNs to the "hosts file" which should be the equivalent of a NETBIOS name (afaik - not my area of expertise).
That way I would have name resolution that did not depend on an external DNS-server and the ability to instantly change the DNS. The "real" DNS-record would simply be a fallback for machines that did not have the "hosts" entries or e.g. had forgotten to re-add them after a hardware replacement.

Are there any gotchas with this method? (issues with Windows or SQL Server). Or is there a better way to accomplish this for our kind of setup?

*(this is a crosspost of an [SQLServerCentral post](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1202832-391-1.aspx) - I'm posting here as well to reach a broader/different audience, since I have not received any really reassuring answers on SSC)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FQDN makes sense. I would say it makes more sense than using an IP. Using DNS is fine and internally the "overhead" of that name resolution should be essentially non-existent. I much prefer to use a FQDN and often times I may not even use the servername but actually create a CNAME alias just for the purpose of server migrations, having to failover to a backup server, etc.

So in this example my app will point to ApplicationNameSQLServer.MyDomain.Com in the SQL connection string... SQLServer1 will be seen as ApplicationNameSQLServer on the network.. Then if SQLServer1 is replaced, migrated away, etc. I have more options than trying to do a careful dance of server renames.

Comment: Thanks Mike. I'm not sure I completely understand all parts of your answer though: "I may not even use the servername" - isn't that implied if you use FQDN?

Comment: In your example: "SQLServer1 will be seen as ApplicationNameSQLServer on the network". But you don't use that name for anything - right? (except perhaps sys-adm stuff unrelated to connection strings)

Comment: So in the case of a server relocation you would simple make a temporary "hosts" entry? - or how would you deal with TTL? (maybe you you have been lucky to never have needed to deal with it :-)

Comment: In a local environment where it is our domains, our DNS, etc. we have been fine to just change the DNS. You could make a local hosts entry for a bit to make you feel more comfortable or if you had issues, though..

Comment: I'll go ahead with a gradual conversion to FQDN connections. Thx.